# S3 prefix for listing objects with paritial uuids

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was curious if it was possible to create an S3 prefix which can scope the object listening to a particular folder depending on having just partial data.

basically the structure is like below, where I can only provide the uuid for uuid1 and uuid2. I can't retrieve the ignoreUuid in order to build up the prefix.

Is it possible for me to filter by only providing uuid1 and uuid2?

I can only do by uuid1 at the moment but the listening can be in the thousands and is quite time intensive.

```
prefer:  S3_SCAN_RESULT_PREFIX = "{uuid1}/files/{ignoreUuid}/{uuid2}";

currently: S3_SCAN_RESULT_PREFIX = "{uuid1}/files/"; (not optional as this can be quite a huge and expensive object listing) 

   objectListing objects = amazonS3Client().listObjects(bucket, format(S3_RESULT_PREFIX, uuid1, uuid2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to natively list objects that match `known1/known2/unknown/known3`.

You would need to rearrange the prefix to bring all known parts to the front, or maintain an index elsewhere (in DynamoDB or an RDBMS, for example).